# How to print sqlite to file in utf-8?

Tags: sql, utf-8, sqlite

I've opened `sqlite3.exe` in windows console and made a database with special characters. 
`.dump` showed me the sql query with special characters.
Then I changed output to file: `.output file.sql`
And executed the `.dump` command.
The special characters were missing when I imported the database using `.read file.sql`.
I used `pragma encoding="UTF-8";` but it didn't change anything (I don't know if it should).

Comment: Try the following commands (which create the string "x×x"): `create table t(x); insert into t values(cast(x'78c39778' as text));` How does this look in the Windows console and in the output file?

Comment: @CL. in windows console: INSERT INTO "t" VALUES('x├Śx'); and in the file: INSERT INTO "t" VALUES('x×x');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows console [makes it hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how) to use UTF-8 correctly, and the Microsoft compiler has [lots of bugs](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/) that make it impossible to use UTF-8 with portable I/O functions.

If you have entered data in the Windows console, those strings are not valid UTF-8.
If a non-ASCII string is output with correct characters in the Windows console, it is not valid UTF-8.

To ensure that your data is valid UTF-8, you have to go through files.
Alternatively, use any SQLite shell that does not use the console (such as the SQLite Manager Firefox extension).

Comment: In Windows console one should type `chcp 65001` to change encoding to UTF-8 and then open `sqlite3.exe` in current window. This encoding change isn't permanent and should be done every time when there's need to change something in a database.

Answer (score -1):

This work fine for CP852, but could be used for any codepage known by iconv.

```
chcp 852 >NUL
echo INSERT into NAMES (name,timestamp) VALUES ('ěščřžýáíé','1429001515'); | iconv.exe -f cp852 -t utf-8 | ..\utilities\sqlite3.exe test.db
```

Windows can handle unicode internaly, but if you print it on console (by 'echo' command for example) than character mismatch. Using on-the-fly reencoding solve this problem.